# Rails 4.1 nested model form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Booking -< Orders -< Transactions

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booking
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I need to be able to create a `Transaction` without an `Order` or `Booking` existing.

**I'm trying to achieve the following:**
When a `Transaction` is created an `Order` and a `Booking` is automatically created. The transaction form can take a `Booking.booking_number` which will be saved to the above automatically created `Booking`.

I'm very new to rails and have tried a combination of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, Ryan Bates' [nested model form part1 screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and `form_fields_for` without success.

Some guidance, not necessarily code, would be much appreciated.

My routes look like: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to be able to create a Transaction without an Order or Booking
>   existing.

Bad system design - surely a transaction would *follow* an order or booking?

From your question, I'd highly recommend creating a booking or order first. This will allow you to create a transaction as a bolt-on to the `order` or `booking`:

```
#app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb
Class BookingsController < ApplicationController
   def create
       booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
       booking.save
   end
end

#app/models/booking.rb
Class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :build_transaction #-> creates a blank transaction which can be populated later
end
```

---

Nonetheless, there's nothing stopping you *creating* a transaction & assigning an order later

You can do this:

```
#app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb
def create
    Transaction.new(transaction_params)
end

#app/models/transaction.rb
Class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :order

    def order
        self.order.create!([order_details?])
    end
end
```

---

If you tell me some more about what you're building, I'll be able to create a more refined response!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may be work.
In your model
        `accepts_nested_attributes_for :order, :allow_destroy => true`
change whether true/false depending on your form

Comment: Ehm, thanks but that doesn't really have anything to do with the question.